# How do I know when to use an enum or a sub-class?

Tags: class, enums, polymorphism

Let's say I am making a game of chess. Would it be more effective to have a base class of Piece()? With sub-classes for each type of piece.

Or, an enum

```
enum Piece{
King,
Queen,
Knight,
etc;
}
```

It also brings me onto a common problem I have when refining data.

```
GameObjects
Piece extends GameObjects
```

Should I stop here and declare the objects with their individual properties?

```
Piece King = new Piece("King",5,10); //just made up values, no significance.
```

Or refine it further and have:

```
King extends Piece
```

and then handle King Pieces in a polymorphic way:

```
Piece king = new King("King,5,10);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Polymorphism

It depends on how you want to structure the logic of your game, but it probably makes sense to define common behavior (methods) and attributes (fields) in an abstract `Piece` class and then have each subtype implement abstract methods (or override default methods) and set values of inherited fields based on the ways that they vary. Maybe something like:

```
public abstract class Piece {
    protected int value;
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public abstract boolean isValidMove(String move);
    public void move(String move) {
        //common logic here
        doMove(move);
    }
    protected abstract void doMove(String move);
}

public class King extends Piece {
    public King() {
        this.value = 20;
    }
    public boolean isValidMove(String move) {
        //specific king logic here
    }
    protected void doMove(String move) {
        //more specific king logic
    }
}
```

This would allow you to use polymorphism to define various pieces with a common `Piece` API, while the important differences are handled by each concrete type.

```
Piece king = new King();
//...
if(king.isValidMove(move)) king.move(move);
```

## Enums

Enums allow you to create a set of optimized singleton instances of a common type, which can also define behavior, but they don't support overriding/implementing type-specific behavior very well because you end up having to check which enum the current instance when implementing variations. You would also end up with a problem of only having a single `KING` or `PAWN` instance when you really need multiples of those for a game (one white king and one black king, 8 white pawns and 8 black pawns).

```
public enum Piece {
    KING(20),
    PAWN(1);
    private int value;
    private Piece(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public boolean isValidMove(String move) {
        switch(this) {
            case KING:
                //king specific logic
                break;
            case PAWN:
                //pawn specific logic
                break;
        }
    }
    public void move(String move) {
        if(this == KING) {
            //king specific logic
        } else if(this == PAWN) {
            //pawn specific logic
        }
    }
}
```

So an enum probably wouldn't work very well in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use an enum when there are a limited and defined number if instances.

In this case, clearly there are a defined number of pieces, so use an enum.

Note that enums can have methods just like a regular class, so enums don't have to be just "values", they can do stuff.

I would not try to cram too much into your enum, and in fact I would name it `PieceType` to make it clear what it represents, and perhaps have a class `Piece` which is an instance of a piece that has a `PieceType`, a location (board square) and a color.

Answer (score 0):

The main distinction is that the set of sub-classes is open-ended: you or other people who use your code can create new sub-classes without breaking old code.
Enums are the opposite: other people cannot add new items to your enum and even you, the maintainer of the code, cannot add new enum constants without double-checking every single switch-case statement.

So, use enums if you do not expect new items to be added to the set. Use sub-classes otherwise. This does not mean that sub-classes are better: if you know the set of options to be closed-ended then you should NOT use sub-classes. If you do, you will find yourself writing `if (... instanceof ...)` chains!

If with enums you find yourself adding new `case`s to your `switch` statements (or you can anticipate that) then switch to sub-classes. And if with sub-classes, you find yourself writing `instanceof` chains, then switch to enums.